# Como eu concateno uma variável em uma classe com função static?

Tags: php, classes, static

Galera estou com um problema, tenho função que ao passar número do cartão retorna o nome da bandeira (visa,mastercard etc)

E eu preciso retornar o nome da bandeira dentro de uma função statica

```
 $bandeira = getBandeiraByNumber("55523131232131"); retorna string visa
 $card->setCreditCardBrand(\Gateway\One\DataContract\Enum\CreditCardBrandEnum::$bandeira);
```

Aqui que está a jogada

```
CreditCardBrandEnum::$bandeira
```

Ele retorna este erro

`Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Gateway\One\DataContract\Enum\CreditCardBrandEnum::$bandeira in /var/www/html/exec/mundipagg/Mundipagg.php on line 148`

Classe abstrata está assim.

namespace Gateway\One\DataContract\Enum;

```
abstract class CreditCardBrandEnum
{
    const VISA = 'Visa';
    const MASTERCARD = 'Mastercard';
    const HIPERCARD = 'Hipercard';
    const AMEX = 'Amex';
    const DINERS = 'Diners';
    const ELO = 'Elo';
    const AURA = 'Aura';
    const DISCOVER = 'Discover';
    const CASASHOW = 'CasaShow';
    const HAVAN = 'Havan';
    const HUGCARD = 'HugCard';
    const ANDARAKI = 'AndarAki';
    const LEADERCARD = 'LearderCard';
}
```

No caso eu quero transformar uma variável em const static, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: O ele tenta ler é `\Gateway\One\DataContract\Enum\CreditCardBrandEnum::visa` Isso existe na classe? Veja a capitalização da constante também, se possível adicione na pergunta.

Comment: @rray sim existe, eu re-editei. da uma olhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa passar o valor correto para acessar a constante, no caso `visa` está minusculo quando deveria estar em maiusculo, use uma função para deixar o returno em letras maiusculas como `strtoupper()` ou `mb_convert_case()` para caracteres com encode multibyte.

```
$bandeira = strtoupper(getBandeiraByNumber("55523131232131"));
$card->setCreditCardBrand($bandeira);
```

ou

```
$bandeira = mb_convert_case(getBandeiraByNumber("55523131232131"), MB_CASE_UPPER);
```

Comment: Funcionou te amo valeu!

Comment: @TutiJapaWada funcinou mesmo?

Comment: Sim era case-sensitive.

Comment: Coloquei um strupper no return da funcao da bandeira

Comment: @TutiJapaWada fiz uns testes aqui não deu certo xD qual versão do php está usando?

Comment: @TutiJapaWada vc fez mais ou menos assim, `$card->setCreditCardBrand(strtoupper($bandeira));` ?

Comment: quase isso, mas eu coloquei strupper no retorno da função $bandeira getBandeiraByNumber